# I can not implement a Cloud Function that creates a topic in the firebase console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement a firebase function, which executes the creation of a topic in the firebase console.

Here is mi code:

```
exports.createGroupTopic = functions.database.ref("/FDSF/equipos/{equipoID}/").onWrite(event => {
let eventSnapshot = event.data;
let nombreEquipo = eventSnapshot.child('nombre').val();
console.log(nombreEquipo);
request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/'+ nombreEquipo,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Content-Length': 0,
    'Authorization':'API_KEY'
  }
}, ...
```

After performing the deploy, observing the output of the console, I get the following error:
[image: Firebase Console Output]

Comment: did you include the `request` module `const request = require('request-promise')` like in [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/ad474614dbe761b1301d958d93c0033275ef457c/url-shortener/functions/index.js)?

Comment: I have successfully added the request module.

However, when I deploy the function, and try to execute it, I get the following error:

"error": "MissingAuthorization"

The server key was obtained from the console as described in the official documentation.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the Authorization header is the server key prefixed by `key=`, as shown in this example in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request):

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

Prefix your server key with `key=`.